# Export Jobs with Transformations in Pentaho Kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I want to export all jobs in my ETL repository but singularly.

I mean that for every job I want to export his own XML (with transformation).

I read a guide on the official website [WIKI FOR EXPORT XML](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Export+repository+to+XML+file) but with that solution I can export all objects in the same file, export only jobs (but always in the same file), export only transformations (same as jobs), the other two options I don't know why cause errors.

However, I can achieve what I want from File -> Export -> To XML... and in this way I'll have the XML of the job opened in the Kettle main view.

I want to automate all this. How is it possible?

Comment: Where are you files? If the are in a file repository (= a folder), they are xml files and it's a matter of copy/paste! If they are in a database repository, then you have the option of exporting them individually. The wiki you mention is for developers to manager bunches of ktr+kjb in one operation.

Comment: you can create a job for doing this, but the problem is you can only export all the jobs or transformation from the given repository.
there is no option of exporting .ktr or .kjb individually.

Comment: "there is no option of exporting .ktr or .kjb individually" that is what I was looking for

Comment: I'll try copy/paste from etl repository